# Is there any magic specifically invented for the elder wand?

Tags: harry-potter

The elder wand is capable of feats of magic that are otherwise thought to be impossible.

Does that mean it can cast magic that no other wizard can cast (ones that would just not work on other wands)?

Or does it merely allow the user to cast magic better than other wizards?

Answer (score 1):

If a spell had been invented that a normal wand can not cast then why would someone have invented it?

They would try it, saw it did not work and discard it. Its not like they would say "Hey! If i had a more powerful wand i could cast this!"

Comment: Perhaps for the same reason that people design computer programs that can't be run on current technology or build imaginary spaceships that need meta-materials that don't exist yet; because it teaches.

Comment: I do believe Ron invented several spells that didn't work. Using the elder wand would have probably killed him.

Comment: Is there a reason the elder wand users wouldn't invent spells themselves? It would make their magic completely unpredictable.